# how to expand column width of specific columns?

Tags: tables

how to expand column width of specific columns in the table? I tried `\begin{tabular}{llc{2cm}c{2cm}cc}` but it doesnt work. here is my code.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
\begin{tabular}{llc{2cm}c{2cm}cc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:30}$}\ \ \ &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:50}$}\ \ \ \\
 &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}
Deterministic \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 0.639 & - & - \\ % 2.833082
& PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 0.741 & - & - \\ % 15390160
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & 0.879 & 0.810 & - & - \\ % 38696497, 41940673
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}
Stochastic & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & - & - & - & - \\ % 2856122
& Ours & 0.863 & 0.850 & - & - \\ %12853578
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when predicting 20 timesteps into the future i.e. $\hat{\text{x}}_{10:30}$ and 40 timesteps into the future o.e. i.e. $\hat{\text{x}}_{10:50}$. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "expand"? Do you want a centered column that is 2cm wide?

Comment: Probably you're interested in `W{c}{2cm}` from the `array` package?

Comment: Please clarify and please also make your code compilable (docmentclass, required packages)

Comment: `Load the `array` package and replace `c{2cm}` with the new specifier `w{c}{2cm}`.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but why not use the lines from the `booktabs` package instead of `\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}`?

Comment: Also unrelated, but please note that a label should be placed after the caption otherwise references will not work correctly. Also please be aware that a combination of `table` and `center` will lead to additional vertical white space that might be undesired. You could use `\begin{table}\centering` instead.

Comment: @leandriis because i copy paste latex code online and work from that because the syntax is legendary ill never be able to understand it

Comment: @Bernard thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code using the new `W` column type from the `array` package. This column type takes two arguments, the first being the desired horizontal alignment of the contents, the second being the column width. In addition to that, I have also loaded the `booktabs` package and used its `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands in order to avoid having to combine `\hline` with manually added space. In addition to that, I have fixed the position of the `\lablel`. To ensure correct referencing, it should be placed after the `\caption`. Lastly, I have also replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` command in order to avoid additional white space around the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llW{c}{2cm}W{c}{2cm}cc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:30}$}\ \ \ &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:50}$}\ \ \ \\
 &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
\midrule
Deterministic \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 0.639 & - & - \\ % 2.833082
& PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 0.741 & - & - \\ % 15390160
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & 0.879 & 0.810 & - & - \\ % 38696497, 41940673
\midrule
Stochastic & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & - & - & - & - \\ % 2856122
& Ours & 0.863 & 0.850 & - & - \\ %12853578
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when predicting 20 timesteps into the future i.e. $\hat{\text{x}}_{10:30}$ and 40 timesteps into the future o.e. i.e. $\hat{\text{x}}_{10:50}$. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I am also glad that the syntax isnt too far at all from what I had.

Answer (score 0):

Since a c column gets its width from the widest member, all you need is to force the width of any member to be a given width.  \makebox[width][c]{text} will do that.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llcccc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:30}$}\ \ \ &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{x}_{0:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{10:50}$}\ \ \ \\
 &  & \makebox[2cm]{SSIM} & \makebox[2cm]{PSNR} & SSIM & PSNR \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}
Deterministic \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 0.639 & - & - \\ % 2.833082
& PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 0.741 & - & - \\ % 15390160
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & 0.879 & 0.810 & - & - \\ % 38696497, 41940673
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}
Stochastic & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & - & - & - & - \\ % 2856122
& Ours & 0.863 & 0.850 & - & - \\ %12853578
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```